# Deep Transition RNN in keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I need to use a Deep Transition RNN in keras (when there are several layers connected in a row inside a recursive block). In my case, I need "image detecting" layers (something like conv2D + maxPool x2) inside a recursive block, so I can apply this to several images of the same thing to get a tensor describing their common features.

I didn't find it in built-in keras tools and I also don't understand how to write my own class of DT-RNN using keras.Functional or keras.Model (the first is for straight-forward NNs, while the second is too abstract. I tried to understand how does built-in code for Functional work and to rewrite it, but it's too complicated). Does anyone know how to solve this?